# cannot reset UIImageView

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uiimageview, uiimagepickercontroller

I am developing an iOS app that can allow a user to pick an image from the gallery(UIImagePicker) and display the image in an UIImageView which is in a different view controller.

In my cameraViewController.m, when didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo is called, it calls the setImageNow method in UploadView.

```
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    NSString *mediaType = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaType];
    [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    if ([mediaType isEqualToString:(NSString *)kUTTypeImage]) {
        UIImage *image = [info
                      objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

        imageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:image];

        **UploadView *myUploadViewController = [[UploadView alloc]init];
        [myUploadViewController setImageNow:imageView.image];**
    }
}
```

In my UploadView.m,

```
- (void)setImageNow:(UIImage*)image{
    NSLog(@"yy: %@",image);
    if(image != nil){
        [selectedImageView setImage:image];
        NSLog(@"xx: %@",selectedImageView.image);
        }
}
```

The NSLog values for xx and yy are the same, so I think it verified selectedImageView is changed to the new image selected by the user. However, in the user interface, the new image is not shown. The default image is still there. There is a default image set to the selectedImageView when the view is loaded and the code is here:

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    if (!(self = [super initWithFrame:frame]))
        return nil;
    NSArray* nibViews = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"UploadView" owner:self options:nil];
    UIView* myView = [nibViews objectAtIndex: 0];
    [super addSubview:myView];
    return self;
}
```

I have tried different ways to solve the problem but none of them works. Does anyone know what's wrong with my code? Thanks!

Comment: any setNeedsDisplay call expected once you change the Image....

Comment: Your problem is:  *myUploadViewController = [[UploadView alloc]init]; You're creating a new instance of UploadView, when you want to be referencing the one you already have.

Comment: Thanks for help. I tried setNeedsDisplay but it doesnt work. So I guess there are some other thing going wrong. How shall I reference the current instance of UploadView in CameraViewController.m and call setImageNow method?